# Suppress Package compiling output in REPL of julia

Tags: julia, read-eval-print-loop

I am using a Package called "DataTables." On the first time compilation of code, REPL is filled with lines of code with warnings and other related things.

I have tried using a semi-colon, but no effect. How can I suppress this unnecessary output in the REPL?

Comment: Which version of Julia are you using as the answer will depend on this. Also note that DataTables.jl package is deprecated so I would not recommend using it unless you have to because you have some legacy code that depends on it.

Comment: I am using V0.6.4 of Julia. I need a Package for displaying data in table format. Is there any other package that I can use and avoid using dataTables. Thanks

Comment: use the `DataFrames` package instead.